# Change "get help" and "translate this app" quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

If have created an app with quickly with the name "Vault"...but in launchpad the name was already taken for a branch i used "vault-encfs" because its a gui for encfs...

now i have a problem with the option "get help" and "translate this app" in the help menu which tries to find vault in launchpad and not vault-encfs...

can i change it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/launchpad-integration/launchpadintegration/main.py", line 48, in main
    pkginfo = PackageInfo.fromPackageName(options.package, logger)
  File "/usr/share/launchpad-integration/launchpadintegration/packageinfo.py", line 219, in fromPackageName
    '"%s"' % package)
launchpadintegration.packageinfo.PackageNotFoundError: Could not look up package info for "vault"
```

Comment: I don't work with Quickly, but it'll probably save these values somewhere. Do a little grep to find it: `grep -Iinr 'vault' *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature actually attempts to determine the Ubuntu package for the application, and then look that up on Launchpad. Because your application is not packaged, the Launchpad integration feature is not able to determine the binary and source package from which it came, and will thus fail to take the user to Launchpad for the online help and translate menu items.

It is perhaps worth reporting a bug against the `launchpad-integration` package, about the feature failing to work with applications which are not packaged in Ubuntu; if one is not already opened.

Comment: thanks! i'll file a bug to `launchpad-integration` and made a whishlist to quickly to add an option to enter manually the urls...